# Android installation/SDK Manager issues

Tags: android

I have downloaded `android-sdk_r08-windows.zip` and installed it in `c:\`.  When I try to run the SDK Manager, it briefly pops up a DOS window then closes.  Trying to run adroid update sdk results in a null pointer exception.  I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the SDK for both android and java multiple times.  This is on windows XP SP3.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

John

```
C:\android-sdk-windows>java -version

java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\android-sdk-windows>tools\android.bat update sdk
[INFO] Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager
No command line parameters provided, launching UI.
See 'android --help' for operations from the command line.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1155)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1134)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:376)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:230)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:107)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterWindowImpl.<init>(UpdaterWindowImpl.java:86)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.UpdaterWindow.<init>(UpdaterWindow.java:54)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showMainWindow(Main.java:297)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:260)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:99)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:88)
```

Answer (score 6):

Apparently my system had a residual .android folder lying around from when I played around with the android SDK over a year ago.  Renaming that file resulted in the SDK Manager coming up.

Comment: I don't understand how you fixed it. I tried to remove .android folder and reinstal all things but SDK Manager still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the JDK path is added to the Environmental variables.Its usually happenes when a JDK/JRE uninstall is succeeded by another JDK install

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), rather than the JRE?

Also, check that your JAVA_HOME variable points to your JDK install path.

Comment: I have the JDK installed with the JAVA_HOME variable pointing to it.

Comment: Also, I've noticed in some threads that they say additional empty directories may need to exist.  For starters, this install has just the add-ons, platforms and tools directories.  I tried adding the platforms-tools directory but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Are you able to use the install .exe rather than the zip?    http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r08-windows.exe

Answer (score 0):

instead of opening android sdk manager open android.bat in tools folder. i think it is sdk\tools

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure that:

1) JDK **or** JRE is installed
2) Within **System Variables**, the **JAVA_HOME** variable is set to your JDK/JRE folder (e.g. *C:\Program Files\Java\jre7*)
3) Your **PATH** variable includes **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**