# Android Studio not showing device chooser at all

Tags: android

Android Studio stopped showing device chooser after building successfully. I have tried reinstalling my Android Studio, cleaning and rebuilding...but i cant get it working again.....

I seem to be getting the error below, in one of the panels.

[image]

**Edit:** I just noticeed that my AVD Manager is also not working. I think this is what is causing the issue,

Comment: does it show the device if you run :  "adb devices" from commandline?  Also try clicking the Disable Plugin button in the above message and the restart Android Studio. Plus "Report to Google"!!      The following seems closest to the Exception you are seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653645/android-installation-sdk-manager-issues

Comment: YES adb devices show me all running devices on commandline

Comment: you may try the solutions suggested in the following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653645/android-installation-sdk-manager-issues

Comment: ok thanks...let me try

Answer (score 0):

Delete your AVD Devices and restart Android Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just delete it and reinstall the SDK